# Send_email in django with data from a view as an HTML page

Tags: python, database, django, django-templates, django-views

Im having a hard time with this. I have a view like this:

```
@login_required
def verFactura(request, id_factura):
    fact = Factura.objects.get(pk = id_factura)
    cliente = Cliente.objects.get(factura = fact)
    template = 'verfacturas.html'
    iva = fact.importe_sin_iva * 0.21
    total = fact.importe_sin_iva + iva

    extra_context = dict()
    extra_context['fact'] = fact
    extra_context['cliente'] = cliente
    extra_context['iva'] = iva
    extra_context['total'] = total

    return render_to_response(template, extra_context)
```

that takes data from the databse and do some math and shows it on a template like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="box">
            <div id="">
                <p id="address">
                    {{fact.nombre_cliente}}
                </p>
                <p id= "numero">
                    {{fact.numero_De_Factura}}
                </p>
                <div id="logo">
                    <img id="image" src="{% static 'img/Home/Logo-Exisoft.png' %}"                 alt="logo" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="clear:both"></div>

            <div id="customer">
                <div id="datos">
                    <p id = "direccion">
                        {{cliente.Direccion}}
                    </p>
                    <br>
                    <p id = "direccion">
                        {{fact.RI}}
                    </p>
                </div>
                <table id="meta">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="meta-head">Fecha</td>
                        <td><textarea id="date">{{fact.fecha_factura}}</textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="meta-head">CUIT</td>
                        <td><div class="due">{{cliente.CUIT}}</div></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <table id="items">
                <tr>
                    <th class="tipo">Tipo de Factura</th>
                    <th class="descripcion">Descripcion</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="item-row">
                    <td><div><textarea>{{fact.tipo_Factura}}</textarea></div></td>
                    <td class="description"><textarea>{{fact.descripcion}}</textarea></td>
                    <td><span class="price">$ {{fact.importe_sin_iva}}</span></td>
                </tr>
             </table>
             <table id="totales">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
                        <td class="total-value"><div id="subtotal">$ {{fact.importe_sin_iva}}</div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="total-line">Iva</td>
                        <td class="total-value"><div id="total">$ {{iva}}</div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td  class="total-line">Precio Pagado</td>
                        <td class="total-value"><textarea id="paid">$ {{total}}</textarea></td>
                    </tr>
              </table>

              <div id="terms"></div>        
        </div><!-- /.box-body -->
    </div><!-- /.box -->
</div>
```

so what this does is go to the view and renders the information for the fields and completes them, pretty simple. The thing is that when the user creates a bill (Factura in spanish) i also save the data from fields like  {{iva}} and {{total}} into the database, so i have this information in two places: database and the template. OK. So what i want to do is to send an email with proper HTML (hopefully this same tables that appear in the template). Because this information is different for every bill (Factura) i can´t send and email with static information, it has to show the information of each of the bills.

So how can i do this?. Take the info from the database and change the value that appears between the tags to show the correct information for each bill.

Thank you in advance. I would really appreciate the help or any idea that points me in the right direction. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in django [`send_mail`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/email/#send-mail) method. You'll see how to send HTML emails as well.

The better solution is to use [`django_templated_email`](https://github.com/bradwhittington/django-templated-email) app which uses the normal django templates to allow you to compose rich HTML emails that it will send out.

It has a very simple API:

```
from templated_email import send_templated_mail
send_templated_mail(
        template_name='welcome',
        from_email='from@example.com',
        recipient_list=['to@example.com'],
        context={
            'username':request.user.username,
            'full_name':request.user.get_full_name(),
            'signup_date':request.user.date_joined
        },
        # Optional:
        # cc=['cc@example.com'],
        # bcc=['bcc@example.com'],
        # headers={'My-Custom-Header':'Custom Value'},
        # template_prefix="my_emails/",
        # template_suffix="email",
)
```

To use it in your view, follow these steps:

1. Install the library `pip install django_templated_email`.
2. Create a `templates` directory in the same directory that you have `views.py` for your application.
3. Inside this `templates` directory you created, create another directory called `templated_email`. Your template emails will go here.

Now, create a file in this `templates/templated_email` directory called `receipt.email`

Copy and paste the following into it:

```
{% block subject %}Your Receipt # {{fact.numero_De_Factura}}{% endblock %}

{% block html %}
<html>
<head>
<title>Receipt</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Receipt Number</th><tr><th>Client Number</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>{{fact.numero_De_Factura}}</td><td>{{fact.nombre_cliente}}</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</html>
{% endblock html %}

{% block plain %}
  Thank you. Your receipt number is: {{fact.numero_De_Factura}} and your client # is {{fact.nombre_cliente}}
{% endblock plain %}
```

You can adjust the HTML to your liking and even inherit from other templates. Make sure you keep the special `{% block html %}` and `{% block subject %}` as this is how the application will create your HTML email and its subject.

Finally, to send the email is the easiest part. Just a few lines in your existing view method:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from templated_email import send_templated_mail

@login_required
def verFactura(request, id_factura):
    fact = Factura.objects.get(pk = id_factura)
    cliente = Cliente.objects.get(factura = fact)
    template = 'verfacturas.html'
    iva = fact.importe_sin_iva * 0.21
    total = fact.importe_sin_iva + iva

    extra_context = dict()
    extra_context['fact'] = fact
    extra_context['cliente'] = cliente
    extra_context['iva'] = iva
    extra_context['total'] = total

    # Send the email
    send_templated_mail(template_name='receipt',
                        from_email='robot@server.com',
                        recipient_list=[request.user.email],
                        context=extra_context)

    return render(request, template, extra_context)
```

Comment: Hello. Yes i was just looking at it. One question: this is going to take the template with the information from the database for each bill and with that make an Email?. Thats the only thing that i dont understand, my english is not so good, sorry

Comment: It is just like you are doing now with your view; except instead of sending the template with the information to the browser, it will send it in an email. In fact, you can use the same template you are using now.

Comment: wow that would really help. Im going to try it and let you know. Thanks for the tip

Comment: You are the man. But i have two question: Can i add this "send_templated_mail" ass a function to a buttom? and i saved the receipt.email just like that, it does´nt have to end with ".html" or ".py" or is it ok to end as ".email"

Comment: The template has to end in `.email` and you can put the function wherever you want, but you have to call it before the `return`, otherwise no email will be sent.

Comment: OK. so now i can do something like -iF "the button is clicked": do "the code you suggested",
eLse: none...and then the return. you thins is a good approach? because i only want to send the email if the user wants to, not always

Comment: Its okay, but my suggestion is to always send the email, even if the user does not want (this by the way, is an option no user will select).  Also, it might be a good idea to store the exact details of the invoice so that it can be regenerated at a later date.